# Semian gem Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-20.04

Fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install, when I try to bundle my project, I get this error which I'm not sure what's producing it.

```
Installing semian 0.10.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/fran/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/semian-0.10.0/ext/semian
/home/fran/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20200922-5726-1n8pgk.rb extconf.rb --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
checking for openssl/sha.h... yes
checking for SHA1() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for sys/ipc.h... yes
checking for sys/sem.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/fran/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/semian-0.10.0/ext/semian
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/fran/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/semian-0.10.0/ext/semian
make "DESTDIR="
compiling resource.c
In file included from /home/fran/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from sysv_semaphores.h:15,
                 from resource.h:10,
                 from resource.c:1:
/home/fran/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:631:1: error: ‘const’ attribute on function returning ‘void’ [-Werror=attributes]
  631 | CONSTFUNC(void rb_secure_update(VALUE));
      | ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/fran/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2008,
                 from /home/fran/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from sysv_semaphores.h:15,
                 from resource.h:10,
                 from resource.c:1:
/home/fran/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/intern.h:257:1: error: ‘const’ attribute on function returning ‘void’ [-Werror=attributes]
  257 | CONSTFUNC(void rb_error_untrusted(VALUE));
      | ^~~~~~~~~
/home/fran/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/intern.h:259:1: error: ‘const’ attribute on function returning ‘void’ [-Werror=attributes]
  259 | CONSTFUNC(void rb_check_trusted(VALUE));
      | ^~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [Makefile:242: resource.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/fran/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/semian-0.10.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/fran/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/semian-0.10.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing semian (0.10.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install semian -v '0.10.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Did not have this problem bundling other projects that require native extensions, just this one where we make use of the semian gem.

Comment: Does it compile if you remove the `-Werror` flag in `.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/semian-0.10.0/ext/semian/extconf.rb`?

Comment: @NathanMills nope, I get the same error :/